# Tableau:Create a calculated field using Case statement and case statement uses a logical calculation

Tags: tableau-api, logical-operators, case-statement

I have a question regarding tableau calculated field.

I am using Sample Super Store data. Below is my questions

I want to Categorize Sales into 'Low Sales','High Sales' and 'Super Sales' based on below

using Case Statements

SUM(Sales)>500000 then categorize as 'Less Sales'
(Sales) between 500000 and 1000000 then 'High Sales'
Else SUM(Sales)>1000000 then 'Super Sales'

After categorising I need to find out the count of [Order] under Super Sales '

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

1. Create 3 sets for `Order ID` 3 conditions:

Set 1:

Right Click Order ID --> Create --> Set Here move to the condition tab and select condition for Sales and value is <50000

Similarly create 2 more sets.

2. Create a calculated field `Display` and write below code:

   IF [Set 1]=TRUE
   THEN "Less Sales"
   ELSEIF [Set 2]=TRUE
   THEN "High Sales"
   ELSEIF [Set 3]=TRUE
   THEN "Super Sales"
   END
3. Place the calcualte field on Rows and Order ID on Columns
4. For order ID select the aggrigation `Count Distinct`

Now you should be able to see the order count for all sales

Comment: @Drishya If statements will do the same action as case but in different way. Why stressing on case statement, Is there any constraint to use only case statement? then I can try